# Auth0Cordova client.authorize() throwing error

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic-framework, auth0

I'm currently working on a SPA using the Ionic Framework. I've decided to use Auth0Cordova. When the user clicks the login button, he is successfully redirected to the Auth0 login form, then when they log in from there, they are redirected back to the Login page, with no indication of having been logged in.

My auth0 config settings are:

```
const auth0Config = {
  clientID : {MYCLIENTID},
  clientId : {MYCLIENTID},
  domain : {MYAPPDOMAIN},
  callbackURL : location.href,
  packageIdentifier : {MYIONICPACKAGENAME}
};
```

When I check the error handler for client.authorize(), I realize that it is throwing an error, but when I try to stringify the JSON version of the error, I get {}. I'm testing on Android. I've remembered to add the file://* protocol to allowed CORS origins in my Auth0 dashboard, and all my auth0 config data is alright. This has me completely puzzled. I don't know why my code is not progressing past client.authorize(). Here is my code below:

```
login(){
const client = new Auth0Cordova(auth0Config);

const options = {
  scope: 'openid profile offline_access'
};

client.authorize(options, (err, authResult) => {

  if(err){
    alert(JSON.stringify(err));
    throw err; //The error occurs around here
  }

  this.setIdToken(authResult.idToken);
  this.setAccessToken(authResult.accessToken);

  const expiresAt = JSON.stringify((authResult.expiresIn * 1000) + new Date().getTime());
  this.setStorageVariable('expires_at', expiresAt);

  this.auth0.client.userInfo(this.access_token, (err, profile) => {
    if(err) {
      throw err;
    }

    profile.user_metadata = profile.user_metadata || {};
    this.setStorageVariable('profile', JSON.stringify(profile));
    this.zone.run(() => {
      this.user = profile;
      this.logged_in = true;
    });
  });
});
```

};

My home.html and home.ts is as follows:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {TabHomePage} from '../tab-home/tab-home';
import { UserServiceProvider } from '../../providers/user-service/user-service';
import { RegistrationPage } from '../registration/registration';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  email : string;
  password : string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public _usp : UserServiceProvider) {

  }

  Login(){
    this._usp.login();
  }

  Go(){
    this.navCtrl.push(TabHomePage);
  }

  Logout(){
    this._usp.logout();
  }

}

<ion-content padding>

  <div text-center class="bottomize">
    <h1>MyApp</h1>
    <div *ngIf="!_usp.logged_in; else otherblock">
      <button ion-button (click)="Login()">Get Started</button>
    </div>
    <ng-template #otherblock>
      <button ion-button (click)="Go()">Go</button>
      <button ion-button (click)="Logout()">Log Out</button>        
    </ng-template>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Please help.

Edit: apparently the error isn't in the form of JSON, but a plaintext string, and when I log it, I get error: User cancelled